# OpenCV Optical Flow using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, depth, opticalflow

How do I perform Optical Flow on a set of images?

I want to read multiple images and perform Optical Flow (Lucas Kanade) on them. However I get solutions only for loading a video and not images.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this line in tutorial:

```py
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Just get the frame this way:

```py
frame = cv2.imread("path/to/img")
```

Comment: Thank you. But the optical flow in tutorial has cv and cv2 functions link:https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html  So how can I use "frame = cv2.imread("path/to/img")"

Comment: Optical flow requires a pair of images, not a single image.

Comment: Just replace all occurrences "cap.read()" with "cv2.imread("path/to/img"+str(img_index)+".png")". And increment img_index then.